# Why does this return -99 all the time?

Tags: java

I have not used java in quite a while and I am getting a little frustrated with this... It always returns -99 but I don't know where the logic is wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(shippingCost('P',10));
}

public static int shippingCost(char packageType, int weight)
{
    String e1 = "Legal Values: Package Type must be P or R";
    String e2 = "Legal Values: Weight < 0";
    int cost = 0;
        if((packageType != 'P')||(packageType != 'R'))
        {
             //throw new Exception(e1);
             return -99;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: I would guess that packageType is always either nor 'P' or not 'R', and either of those satisfies the `||` in your `if`.

Comment: `packageType == 'P'` hence `if (false||true)` hence `if (true)`. || (or) should be && (and).

Comment: My IDE (IntelliJ) displays "*Condition ... is always 'true'*" here...

Comment: (Must be the start of the new semester.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your if() should be using an `AND`. Since it's an `OR` now, it is ALWAYS true that your packageType is neither P or R.

Answer (score 3):

Your if is wrong. ((Not P) or (Not R)) will always be true since one of the nots always will be true.

Comment: This isn't true as P and R are *not* implicitly dependent and no explicit dependence was added, however when expanded, `(X != P) OR (X != R)` (by DeMorgan) -> `!(X == P AND X == R)` and `X` can't be `P` if it's `R` or vice-versa (unless `P == R`, of course).

Comment: I'm a bit baffled as to why you are saying I'm wrong, when we're essentially posting the same thing. Since it's chars, 'P' and 'R' will never be equal.

Comment: I am saying that P and R are *not implicitly dependent*. I made the dependence explicit by defining `P` and `R` in relation to `X` (with pseudo-code to mirror the initial post). Without such a *dependence*, `P` *or* `R` could *each* be false (or true) without affecting the other: draw out the truth-table for the above to see.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is checking if the packageType is not equal to 'P' OR it is not equal to 'R'.  This will always resolve to true, which means your function will always return -99.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to use `AND` instead of `OR`. Try

```
if((packageType != 'P') && (packageType != 'R'))
                        ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Because package type is not 'R'!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the if statement.  Since your condition is "not P OR not R" then if your're passing  P to the method it is going to evaluate to true. This is because it is not P but it is also not R, so therefore it evaluates to true.

Sonny